# How to display all prime numbers that are less than or equal to the number a user enters

Tags: c++, vector, foreach, primes

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    bool is_prime = true;
    vector<int> num;
    cout << "Hello please enter a number larger than 1: ";

    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        cin >> num[i];
        if (num[i] == 0 || num[i] == 1) {
            is_prime = false;
        }
    }

    for (int j = 2; j <= num[j] / 2; j++) {
        if (num[j] % j == 0) {
            is_prime = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    for (int p = 0; p < num[p]; p++) {
        if (is_prime) {
            cout << "This is the prime number: " << num[p] << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << "This number is not a prime number: " << num[p] << endl;
        }
    }

}
```

I'm currently working on my own little project that I have going on here, and I'm currently trying to understand this slightly better. Currently I'm writing a program that asks the user to enter a number larger than 1; and then displays all the prime numbers that are less than or equal to the number entered. For instance: if I entered 29, it would populate the vector with all numbers from 0 and up to the number the user entered. This would then lead me to use the `For_each` function to pass each element of the array through the function that checks if the number is a prime number. Currently I'm trying to get a clear understanding if I should create a function that separates the "Prime number finder" and the populating of the array. I figured I could do both but for some reason right now I'm getting an error in visual studio that says "Vector subscript out of range".

Comment: `vector<int> num;` is an empty vector. `cin >> num[i];` accesses that empty vector out of bounds. Either `reasize()` the vector or use `push_back()` to add items.

Comment: "...it would populate the vector with all numbers from 0 and up to the number the user entered...". You never actually need to store the numbers from 0 to anything, because whenever you enumerate the elements of such an array, each element is identical to its index. So just use the index.

Comment: Would anybody know how to for instance, if you inputted a number 10, you could write code so that you would see all the numbers leading up to 10?

Comment: @John ```int bound; cin >> bound; for (int i = 0; i < bound; i++) cout << i << endl;```

Comment: When I read code like this I think `vector::operator[]` should be removed. Replace all the `num[x]` with `num.at(x)` and every time it throws an out-of-bounds exception think about what you wrote.

Answer (score 1):

Your prime test is not as efficient as it could be. The test only needs to go as far as the square root of the number (inclusive) and you do not need to test even divisors larger than 2.

Here is some pseudocode:

```
boolean function isPrime(num)
  // 1, 0 and negatives cannot be prime,
  if (num < 2) return false

  // 2 is the only even prime number.
  if (num % 2 == 0) return (num == 2)

  // Check for odd factors.
  limit = 1 + isqrt(num)
  for (test = 3 to limit step 2)
    if (num % test == 0) return false
  end for

  // No factors so number is prime.
  return true
end function
```

The `isqrt()` function returns the integer square root of a number: `isqrt(42)` gives 6. The added 1 is a safety factor in case 6.99999 gets rounded to 6 for isqrt(49). My own version uses Newton-Raphson for an integer result.

Answer (score 0):

One of the simplest and most efficient prime finding algorithms. Used with an upper bound (seems like your case).
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes